# object oriented MATLAB: static method from parent can't set protected property from child

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, properties, static-methods

Ok, so I have a parent class `MOM` with a bunch of properties with the SetAccess attribute set to `protected`. It has a special static method `setProperty` for setting its properties:

```
classdef MOM < handle
    properties (SetAccess = 'protected')
        age;
        occupation;
        num_kids;        
        MOMmusthaves ={'age','occupation','num_kids'};
    end
    methods
        function obj = MOM(varargin)            
            if iscell(varargin{1,1})
                varargin =varargin{1,1};
            end
            inputstrings=varargin(cellfun(@isstring,varargin)); % get strings out of the inputs
            if(isempty(setxor(intersect(inputstrings,obj.MOMmusthaves),obj.MOMmusthaves)))
                % if all proper inputs are entered, initialize your object
                for pp =1:length(obj.MOMmusthaves)
                    obj.setProperty(obj,varargin,obj.MOMmusthaves{pp});%find each input in the vararagins, and set it
                end
            else
                display('Hey! These inputs are wrong. type help MOM for an example. Make sure you inlcude inputs for all of the following:');                obj.MOMmusthaves
                return;
            end

        end

    end

    methods (Static)
        function setProperty(obj,varargs,xx)
            eval(sprintf('obj.%s = varargs{find(strcmp(''%s'',varargs))+1};',xx,xx));
        end
    end

end
```

Then I have a child object `KID`, which has a couple more properties, also SetAccess `protected`. When I try to use `MOM`'s static method to set a `KID` property inside the `KID`'s constructor I get an error :(
The error says:

> You cannot set the read-only property 'allowance' of KID.

Basically, it seems like `KID` doesn't think that it can use `MOM`'s static method as its own (so didn't inherit it properly).

MY QUESTION IS: 
Is there any way I can make the static method be recycled and usable to KID for its own protected properties?

JUST FYI, here's something like the `KID` code;

```
classdef KID < MOM
    properties (SetAccess = 'protected')
        gender;
        allowance;
        favoritecandy;
        KIDmusthaves ={'gender','allowance','favoritecandy'};
    end
    methods
        function obj = KID(varargin)

            obj = obj@MOM(varargin(:)); % Special construct for instantiating the superclass
            inputstrings=varargin(cellfun(@isstring,varargin)); % get strings out of the inputs.

            if(isempty(setxor(intersect(inputstrings,obj.KIDmusthaves),obj.KIDmusthaves)))
                % if all proper inputs are entered, initialize your object
                for pp =1:length(obj.KIDmusthaves)
                    %find each input in the vararagins, and set it
                    obj.setProperty(obj,varargin,obj.KIDmusthaves{pp});
                end
            else
                display('please use correct input format. Make sure you include inputs for all of the following:');
                obj.KIDmusthaves
                return;
            end

        end

    end
end
```

Comment: `eval` is really evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the exact source of the error is; although, I think it may be due to the mutation of the handle object being hidden by the `eval`.

Regardless, if I understand the intended usage of `setProperty`, I think it may be easiest to write the function in a non-`static` form using dot notation (similar to [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) with structs):

```
methods
    function [] = setProperty(obj,musthaves,varargin)
        keys   = varargin(1:2:end);
        values = varargin(2:2:end); 
        for pp =1:length(keys)
            key = keys{k};
            if any(strcmp(musthaves,key))
                obj.(key) = values{pp};
            end
        end
    end
end
```

where `musthaves` is any cell array of property strings
You could also have `musthaves` be a string that indicates the `obj` property holding the property list:

```
methods
    function [] = setProperty(obj,musthaves,varargin)
        keys   = varargin(1:2:end);
        values = varargin(2:2:end); 
        for pp =1:length(keys)
            key = keys{k};
            if any(strcmp(obj.(musthaves),key))
                obj.(key) = values{pp};
            end
        end
    end
end
```